# How to clone input field object and have both original and cloned fields be referenced in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have these input fields which I am using jQuery to clone when say "EDIT" button is clicked so I can manipulate the edit display better but I need user input to be referenced to the original so that when they are done editing, the original input fields will contain the value they inputted.

So consider this simple html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="settings" style="display:none;">
          <label>Title</label><input type="text" name="title" value="" />
          <label>Text</label><input type="text" name="text" value="" />
     </div>
     <a href="#" class="edit">Edit Fields</a>
</div>
```

So this is my initial form and settings are hidden on page load.  Only when user clicks the edit fields button is when the settings appear but I want it to appear inside a modal lightbox is why I am cloning them for display manipulation.

```
$('.edit').click(function() {
     var cloned = $('.wrapper .settings').clone(true, true),
         popup = $('<div class="popup"></div>');

     popup.append(cloned);
     $('body').append(popup);
});
```

Ok so I got as far as making the modal popup with the correct information of the settings but I am not sure how the user inputted value will populate on the original fields.  That is why I asked if the jQuery clone function can do a reference type copy.

Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why not use on blur original field.val = this.val ?

Comment: But how would you map the value to the original?  All fields are dynamically added.

Comment: Uuuuuhm. Give them both a class. The same, and not shared with any other element. Then you know the first element with that class is the original, and the second one is the copy, be it with getElementsByClass('myClass') (JS) or $('.myClass') (jQuery). Or I may have misunderstood your problem.

Comment: `$('element').clone(true)` keeps the event handlers ?

Comment: Well, you'll can use extended selectors like `$('wrapper > settings > label + input[name="title"] + label + input[name="text"]').val()`

Comment: @adeneo - yeah I tried that but that only means to keep the event handlers on the cloned object...but it still doesn't link the two as reference

Comment: When you create a new clone, just add a keyup event that sets the value on the original to the same as the clone.

Comment: By class name selector coz both have the same class name

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: @adeneo - yes however if I have 100s of inputs, that would definitely be long-winded to write keyups for each and every element and as I mentioned they are dynamically added.

Comment: You don't write an event handler for every single element, but without seeing how you create these elements and the lightbox, it's really hard to formulate an answer!

Comment: I just edited with JS code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.edit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elems  = $('.wrapper .settings'),
        cloned = elems.clone();

    cloned.find('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function() {
        elems.find('[name="'+this.name+'"]').val( this.value );
    });

    $('.popup').append(cloned.show());
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/EMUgP/)

Comment: I see you have show() on the settings in the fiddle.  But will this still work if it were hidden?

Comment: Hey thanks again for your answer...I just realized I actually don't need to use clone and instead I could just use appendto() and put it back when done editing....I am so dumb...